# Write unit test for checking code coverage in python

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

I need to write test using unittest in python that fails when coverage is less than 50 percent. 
Such as:

```
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    cov = coverage.Coverage()
    cov.load()
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as f:
        self.total = cov.report(file=f)

def test_compare_values(self):
    self.assertGreaterEqual(self.total, 20)
```

But when tests are running the file coverage is locked and cannot be opened.

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to read the coverage data from a test. Instead use the `--fail-under=50` option on the coverage report command.